# Can a website switch from wordpress cms to ruby on rails or any other framework?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress

I am almost finished with a website build with wordpress. My main concern is can a wordpress website be switched to ruby on rails for example without losing database, passwords, users, products etc etc?

I know that mashable  did that too.

Is this a super hard thing to manage? Please explain with an ease of words because i m not that hardcore and i will probably hire developers to do this job in the near future. This is just so i know what my next moves are going to be. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not easily. The files and database aren't compatible so you would need to either find or write a converter to transfer all the data.

Comment: So it is doable. The developer that is going to do this job what skills should aquire? wordpress or ruby?

Comment: clearly both; but is there any great advantage in doing it at all

Comment: I believe ruby on rails are any other than wordpress are far more scalable and more flexible than wordpress when many users are on it

Comment: They would need to understand both wordpress and ruby as well as php for some wordpress stuff (converting/generating passwords) and also whatever cms you choose in ruby (as rails isn't a cms). And there would be some custom work to whatever cms you choose, specifically for stuff like the passwords to make the compatible and possibly convert a password entered to whatever the new cms requires. Sounds like a big pain to me and something I personally wouldn't want to deal with.

Comment: sounds like an expensive project based on 'belief' - well its your money

Comment: Okay guys, thanks a lot. I just wanted to see if it was doable. I clearly will need more than one developer and of course they need to be experienced. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a website switch from wordpress cms to ruby on rails or any other framework?

This isn't really a meaningful question.

Yes, of course you can *rewrite* a website from one language to any other language. You can port your data from one format to another. Nothing (except for time and expense) will prevent you from picking a new language and starting over.

But you cannot "switch" from a PHP-based CMS to Ruby on Rails. It's a complete, from-scratch rewrite. PHP and Ruby are completely different languages, and WordPress and Rails are completely different frameworks. You cannot freely "switch" between them. You're starting over.

Comment: Valid points there. If i can make one more question. You said if you switch to RoR is like scratch-rewrite. So if we move to clean php will that be more helpful and easier to implement? What i am asking is, if in the near future we decide to abandon wordpress to gain scalability and flexibility from php can we do that? Thanks

Comment: why do you think wordpress is not scalable or flexible??

Comment: Because in the long run it is not. And i already made a mistake to start a multi-vendor e-commerce on it and i know it will lag in the future and limit our visions or whatever we want. "missread  your question" and edited my comment

Comment: you made the assertion that it was, you never asked.

Comment: "missread your question" and edited my comment

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails is fundamentally different from Wordpress in that it does not give you a functional website to begin with. A RoR app can offer more functionality than Wordpress probably ever will but you need to code it all alone.

Of course you can write a program that is able to transfer your WP database into a RoR database. For that to happen, you will have to have a schema in your app that resembles the WP database structure. And you may especially run into trouble with the passwords because they are never stored in an unencrypted format so that your developers will have to somehow integrate the WP password encryption functions into your RoR system.

And, of course, RoR is not a CMS as WP is. If you do not want to store and manage data semantically different from WP's, I will strongly discourage you from having a complete new app developed, considering how much it is that needs to be re-implemented and how large the cost of migration might grow.

Comment: If we forget about RoR but move into clean php and move away from wordpress? is that easier? sorry for being a noob

Comment: What is easier depends on your requirements. The first step is to define your goals, and after that you should decide what programming language, let alone framework, to use.
If you are fine with simple blogging, WP definitely meets your goals.


PHP can be easier than Ruby for web servers because it was made specifically for that purpose. You will find more PHP developers. But if you need MVC, the beauty and compactness of Ruby (which makes it fast to develop with) or any of the other features that RoR brings with itself, you might want to use it. There are also MVC frameworks for PHP, though.